# proof that this is an isometric map (on a $C^*$-module)

Tags: functional-analysis, modules, inner-products, c-star-algebras

Are my steps right? I'm not sure about the statement in bold below.

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra. Let $X$ be an $A$-module.

Let $x\in X$, let $a= \langle x,x \rangle $
Define $\lambda _a (z) = az$, $z\in X$.

I want to show that $\| \lambda _a \| = \| a \| $

Let $e_\alpha = \langle u_\alpha , v_\alpha \rangle $ be an approximate identity for the $C^*$-algebra $\langle X,X\rangle $, **such that $u_\alpha $ and $v_\alpha $ are norm bounded by $1$.** ( is this statement true? I know that all $C^*$-algebras have bounded approximate identities)

it is easy to see that $\| \lambda _a \| \leq \| a \| $

Moreover,

\begin{align*}
\| ae_\alpha \| &= \| \langle au_\alpha , v_\alpha \rangle \| = \| \langle \lambda _a (u_\alpha ),v_\alpha \rangle \| \\
& \leq \| \lambda _a (u_\alpha ) \| \| v_\alpha \| \leq \| \lambda _a \|
\end{align*}

Therefore, $\| a \| \leq \| \lambda _a \| $ and hence, $\| a \| = \| \lambda _a \| $

Comment: What does it mean $a=\langle x,x\rangle$ ?

Comment: $\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle $ denotes the inner product

Comment: the inner product from $X \times X$ to $A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see that $\|\lambda_a\|\geq \|a\|$, consider $\|\lambda_a(x)\|$.